# Can Amazon Simple Notification Service "push" notifications to a desktop client?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

Can Amazon Simple Notification Service "push" notifications to a desktop client? It this possible as a true push without polling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not (yet) available out of the box - [Amazon SNS](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/) indeed works by [publishers sending messages to topics](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sns/latest/gsg/Publish.html), which in turn *push* these to endpoints [subscribed to this topic](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sns/latest/gsg/Subscribe.html). The currently available protocols for the [Subscribe API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html) are:

- http -- delivery of JSON-encoded message via HTTP POST
- https --delivery of JSON-encoded message via HTTPS POST
- email -- delivery of message via SMTP
- email-json -- delivery of JSON-encoded message via SMTP
- sms -- delivery of message via SMS *[currently limited to the US region(s)]*
- sqs -- delivery of JSON-encoded message to an Amazon SQS queue

So the closest you currently have for push notifications to a desktop client is email, though it should be relatively easy to build custom ones by posting HTTP to a respective web service, which in turn could facilitate [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or [Growl](http://growl.info/) etc.

Good luck!

Comment: Or your desktop app could implement a simple webserver

Comment: But then if your desktop is offline, you've missed the message. There are several other disadvantages to using a local webserver for SNS notifications, I would not recommend it.